# Why does Spark Streaming save each Kafka message as a single file?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have configured Spark Streaming to receive data from Kafka, following the [Kafka Integration Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html).

I configure Spark Streaming's duration to 20 seconds, and I try to save every 20 seconds received messages to HDFS, using DStream method `saveAsTextFile`

I successfully run the application, and it successfully receives data from Kafka and saves every 20 seconds messages to HDFS. But I am confused about the output layout. It's cool every 20 seconds a directory with prefix specified by the parameter of `saveAsTextFile` is created, containing some output files with prefix "part-" such as "part-00001"

However, there is only one message content in each output file. It seems Kafka DStream save each message received to a single output file in HDFS. I am looking forward to save multiple messages to one output file.

BTW, I am using Spark Standalone deployment and having **only one worker**.

Comment: could you add code that reproduces the issue you're facing?

Answer (score 1):

No, that's certainly not how it works; that would be crazy. One directory is created per batch interval. The contents are `part-*` files that contain *all* messages sent in that interval. One file is created per streaming task, which is basically the number of partitions of the streaming RDD.

Comment: Yes, one file is created per streaming task. I check web-ui and found out that the saveAsTextFile stage is executed with multiple tasks. It seems that spark splits the stage into multiple tasks running in multiple threads. And it is the configured duration and message rate that make it look like one file is created per message. Anyway thank you Sean, I figure this out with your tips that one file is created per streaming task.

Answer (score 0):

**Re-partition** the rdd to 1 before calling `saveAsTextFile` method. you will get single output file. BTW it will add more computation overhead!!